# Alamofire responseArray String array for keyPath

Tags: swift, alamofire, objectmapper

I have a rest call which returns array of string [String] for keyPath "data", for example...

```
{
  "data": [
    "1",
    "3",
    "5",
    "2",
    "4",
    "9"
  ]
}
```

I am trying to get it via `responseArray(keyPath: "data")`, but get compile error for line `*.responseArray(keyPath: "data") {(response: DataResponse<[String]>) in*`

> Cannot convert value of type '(DataResponse<[String]>) -> ()' to expected argument type '(DataResponse<[_]>) -> Void'

Part of request example

```
alamofireManager.request(url)
        .responseArray(keyPath: "data") {(response: DataResponse<[String]>) in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
           if let data = response.result.value {
                //process success
            } else {
                // handle error
            }
        }
        ...
```

Does anybody of you know how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that String isn't Mappable. As per https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/issues/487, these are the proposed solutions:

> In this situation I would recommend accessing the data directly from the Alamofire response. You should be able to simply cast it to [String].
>
> Alternatively, you may be able to subclass String and make the subclass Mappable, however I think that is more work than necessary for the your situation

---

Using Swift's 4 Codable (no external dependencies):

```
struct APIResponse: Decodable {
    let data: [String]
}

let url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1cm14l"
Alamofire.request(url).responseData { (response) in

    if response.result.isSuccess {
        if let jsonData = response.result.value,
            let values = try? JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse.self, from: jsonData).data {
            //process success
            print(values)
        } else {
            // handle error
        }
    }
}
```